# How can i create thumbnails with image, with coord X-0, Y-0

Tags: laravel, image-processing, thumbnails, crop, voyager

Voyager creates a crop on from the center, and I need to crop the beginning of the image. How do I do this? Only the width and height of the crop are specified in the documentation.

```
"name": "cropped",
        "crop": {
            "width": "300",
            "height": "250"
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right in there [documentation about cropping](https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/bread/introduction-1/media-picker#crop) it shows

```
"thumbnails": [
    {
        "type": "crop",
        "name": "crop-500-500",
        "width": 500, // Required
        "height": 500, // Required
        "x": 50, // Optional. Left offset
        "y": 50, // Optional. Top offset
    }
]
```

Comment: These are settings for media picker, but not for imagepicker

Comment: @ИванАпевалов but in image picker you can move the crop to the position that you want no ?